# Pythonic way of copying a non-zero value list to fill in the zeroes of another list

Tags: python, list

This is the list of numbers I want to put into another list replacing all zero values

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 9]
```

here's what the other list should look like before replacing all zero values

```
b = [0, 7, 9, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4]
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to copy the first list in to the second list so it replaces all the zero values like so

```
c = [2, 7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 3, 9, 4]
```

If there are too many zeroes in `b`, it will just be ignored and will stay 0 in `c` and if the there are too few zeroes in `b`, some values in a would simply not be carried over or copied to `c`

**edit**

and is there a way to do this to fill a list like this

```
b = [[0, 3, 9, 1, 3]
     [3, 3, 4, 2, 0]
     [3, 5, 5, 0, 2]
     [0, 0, 3, 8, 9]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

so that `c` will be

```
c = [[2, 3, 9, 1, 3]
     [3, 3, 4, 2, 5]
     [3, 5, 5, 6, 2]
     [3, 9, 3, 8, 9]
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `iter` to create an object giving each element in `a` one-by-one, and then use an ordinary listcomp:

```
>>> a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 9]
>>> b = [0, 7, 9, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4]
>>> fill = iter(a)
>>> c = [x if x != 0 else next(fill) for x in b]
>>> c
[2, 7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 3, 9, 4]
```

As @bulbus notes, this will raise a StopIteration exception if you don't have enough zeros to fill.  You could use the default value for `next`, e.g. `next(fill, 0)` if you want to avoid that.

For your 2D case, the same approach works, we just need to change the listcomp:

```
>>> fill = iter(a)
>>> b = [[0, 3, 9, 1, 3], [3, 3, 4, 2, 0], [3, 5, 5, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> c = [[x if x != 0 else next(fill) for x in row] for row in b]
>>> c
[[2, 3, 9, 1, 3], [3, 3, 4, 2, 5], [3, 5, 5, 6, 2], [3, 9, 3, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: this will fail if there are too many zeros... `[x if x != 0 else next(fill,0) for x in b]`

Comment: @bulbus: I tend to prefer errors to silent extensions, but you're right that some people feel differently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case, the simplest, most readable method is best:

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 9]
b = [0, 7, 9, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4]
new_list = []
count = 0
for i in b:
    if i == 0:
       new_list.append(a[count])
       count += 1
    else:
       new_list.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[2, 7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 3, 9, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make sure your `a` series is long enough:

```
a_long = itertools.chain(a, itertools.repeat(0))
```

That will supply endless zeroes after exhausting the original `a`.

Then, we'll create an iterator for that series, so we can selectively pull the `next()` value:

```
a_iter = iter(a_long)
```

Finally, generate `b` with replacements from the `a` series for as long as they're available:

```
result = (bval if bval != 0 else next(a_iter) for bval in b)
```

Results:

```
>>> a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 9]
>>> b = [0, 7, 9, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2]

>>> import itertools
>>> a_long = itertools.chain(a, itertools.repeat(0))
>>> a_iter = iter(a_long)

>>> result = (bval if bval != 0 else next(a_iter) for bval in b)
>>> result
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10aab1af0>
>>> list(result)
>>> [2, 7, 9, 3, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 3, 9, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2]
```

Note that all the intermediate values (a_long, a_iter) are iterable, so they can handle ultra-long series without a huge memory allocation. And the result is a generator, so it only keeps one value at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to modify `b` in place (or copy `b` to `c` first then modify `c` if you want it in `c`):

```
import numpy as np 

a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 9]
b = np.array(b)
```

Then assign directly the elements of `a` in turn to each element in `b` where it is `0`:

```
>>> b[b==0]=a     # len(a)>=the number of 0's in this case...
```

Or, construct a list of `a` elements or a default value:

```
>>> b[b==0]=a+[0]*(np.count_nonzero(b==0)-len(a))
               ^             0 used as default for elements not found in a
```

Or, you can loop of the index tuples where `b` is 0 and assign either the next value from `a` or a default value:

```
vals=iter(a)
for t in zip(*np.where(b==0)):
    b[t]=next(vals, 0)
```